# Stop Modifications in new feature Branch from Merging into Master using GitGui

Tags: git, github, merge, branching-and-merging, git-gui

For some time I have been modifying small files (typically documentation or styles) in our git repository. Recently a developer started working on a new search feature and subsequently created a new branch - let's call it 'new_search'. The process I had followed up until recently was to:

1. Using Git Gui, Fetch From Origin / Master. This would bring down to my computer all the modifications that had taken place.
2. I would then select Merge, Local Merge to ensure nothing conflicted on my machine
3. I would change my file (let's say a spelling mistake on a labels file) and then I would push my changes and all okay.

Now however, at step 2 I see a dialog come up with 'Merge into master' then origin/new_search (i.e. the new feature our developer is working on). If I read this screen literally I believe her changes will be merged in to the trunk (which I don't want to happen because they are not finished and a variety of other reasons).

After going through Stack Overflow I attempted to remove the branch from my local machine using git branch -d -r origin/new_search then severed the links to the new feature branch by running the commands git config --unset branch.new_search.remote and git config --unset branch.new_search.remote but every time I do a Fetch from Origin request (step 1 above) I see the New Feature branch added again.

How do I prevent this branch from merging in to master. To be honest, i don't even want to see or 'worry' about the new feature changes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just stop using the gui and use `git pull origin master`. I suspect you may have used `git pull` which will pull EVERYTHING if you don't configurated any tracking information. Thats why `new_search` is pulled also.

Comment: Hi mate definitely not using 'PULL' I only ever use Fetch. When I use Fetch from the Git Bash terminal window I get the same result.